# PowerApps with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powerapps

I am trying add my PowerApps account in PowerShell. I am unable to add my account as shown below I am getting the following error

[image]

what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution : Before adding the PowerApps account in PowerShell just run the command as shown in the below image.

[image]

If the Execution Policy is "Restricted" you may be getting errors.The Execution Policy need to be set to "RemoteSigned".